# disable indy TIdTCPClient connect retries in firemonkey

Tags: firemonkey, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

i have this code to check connection to my server
so code is like this:

```
function CheckInternet(ssip:string): boolean;
begin
result:=false;
with form1.IdTCPClient1 do
  try
    ReadTimeout:=2000;
    ConnectTimeout:=1000;
    Port:=80;
    Host:=ssip;
    Connect;
    Disconnect;
    result:=true;
  except
    on E:EIdSocketError do
      result:=false;
    end;
end;
```

after running:
if server is online every thing is ok
but if server is online i got a lot of this error:

[image]

there is not difference in `debug` or `release` mode! both have error 
also in android this cause two app crash and dont handling remain code!!..
how can i avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see can happen only if you are calling `CheckInternet()` in a loop in the main UI thread and not catching raised exceptions.  The popup messages are being displayed by a default exception handler within FMX when it catches an uncaught exception.

`EIdSocketError` is not the only type of exception that `Connect()` can raise.  There are several other possible types, which you are not catching.  You should remove the filter from your `except` block:

```
function CheckInternet(ssip:string): boolean;
begin
  result:=false;
  with form1.IdTCPClient1 do
  try
    ConnectTimeout:=1000;
    Port:=80;
    Host:=ssip;
    Connect;
    Disconnect;
    result:=true;
  except
    result:=false;
  end;
end;
```